# Alternate row color in ListView in Android Studio

Tags: android, listview, android-studio

i want to read a xml file and show the items in a ListView,,,,now i can do it and after it i want to alternate row colors in ListView and i find a solution in [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13109840/android-alternate-row-colors-in-listview) ,,,but i have a problem with getView method,,,what is my problem?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
ArrayAdapter<App> adapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    EditText EDSearch= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EDSearch);
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    List<App> apps = null;
    try {
        XMLPullParserHandler parser = new XMLPullParserHandler();
        InputStream is=getAssets().open("main.xml");
        apps = parser.parse(is);

       adapter =new ArrayAdapter<App>
                (this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, apps);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

    //Text Changed for search in ListView
    listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    EDSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            MainActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
        }
    });
}

// fill the listview by xml file
public class App {

    private int id,location;
    private String title,activtiy,address;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    public String getActivtiy() {
        return activtiy;
    }
    public void setActivtiy(String activtiy) {
        this.activtiy = activtiy;
    }
    public int getLocation() {
        return location;
    }
    public void setLocation(int location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return id + "\n " + title + "\n" +activtiy+"\n"+location+"\n"+address;
    }
```

//Here is my problem,,,cant reolve getView

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        if (position % 2 == 1) {
            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        } else {
            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
        }
        return view;
    }
}

public class XMLPullParserHandler {

    private List<App> root= new ArrayList<App>();
    private App app;
    private String text;

    public List<App> getApps() {
        return root;
    }

    public List<App> parse(InputStream is) {

        try {
            XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
            factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
            XmlPullParser  parser = factory.newPullParser();

            parser.setInput(is, null);

            int eventType = parser.getEventType();
            while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                String tagname = parser.getName();
                switch (eventType) {
                    case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                        if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("row")) {
                            app = new App();
                        }
                        break;

                    case XmlPullParser.TEXT:
                        text = parser.getText();
                        break;

                    case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                        if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("row")) {
                            root.add(app);
                        }else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("id")) {
                            app.setId(Integer.parseInt(text));
                        }
                        else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("title")) {
                            app.setTitle(text);
                        }
                        else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("activity")) {
                            app.setActivtiy(text);
                        }
                        else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("location")) {
                            app.setLocation(Integer.parseInt(text));
                        } else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("address")) {
                            app.setAddress(text);
                        }
                        break;

                    default:
                        break;
                }
                eventType = parser.next();
            }

        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

        return root;
    }
}
```

this is my layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.asaravani.sqlserver.MainActivity">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="500px"
    android:divider="#d8d8d8"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/EDSearch">

</ListView>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/EDSearch"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="کلمه مورد نظر را وارد کنید" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

Comment: in a App Class below of toString method

Comment: @AliSaravani where is you design layout?

Comment: @AliSaravani I mean you wrote in the Adapter right?

Comment: @KNeerajLal if i know it,,,i can do it bro

Comment: No your getting one color?

Comment: @SuryaBondada can not resolve method getView....

Comment: @AliSaravani can you post your log

Comment: @SuryaBondada here is my error http://uploads.im/7bsUj.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You need a to write a CustomAdapter to do this. The `getView` method belongs to an adapter and not an Activity. You are trying to write the `getView` method inside the activity, which is the cause of your error.

[This](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#adapterown) is how you create a custom adapter.

Comment: can u create a CustomAdapter for resolve my problem?

Comment: Check the link, learn how to do it, update your adapter code in the question. Will check.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement an custom adapter for that. I give you an example and i have put in the change of background color for each list item and it works fine. Remember to use viewHolder for each list item components.

```
public class EarnRedeemAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private List<GroupData<Merchant>> sortMerchants = new ArrayList<>();
    private Transformation transformation;
    private boolean earnFlag = true;

    public EarnRedeemAdapter(Context context, List<GroupData<Merchant>> list) {
        this.context = context;
        this.sortMerchants = list;
        UtuAppRunningStorage.wrapperMerchantList.clear();
    }

    public EarnRedeemAdapter(Context context, List<GroupData<Merchant>> list, boolean earnFlag) {
        this.context = context;
        this.sortMerchants = list;
        this.earnFlag = earnFlag;
        UtuAppRunningStorage.wrapperMerchantList.clear();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return sortMerchants.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return sortMerchants.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_earn_redeem, parent, false);
            viewHolder.iv_item_earn_redeem_merchant_icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_item_earn_redeem_merchant_icon);
            viewHolder.tv_item_earn_redeem_merchant_points = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_item_earn_redeem_merchant_points);
            viewHolder.tv_item_earn_redeem_merchant_name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_item_earn_redeem_merchant_name);
            viewHolder.tv_item_earn_redeem_merchant_category = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_item_earn_redeem_merchant_category);
            viewHolder.tv_item_earn_redeem_merchant_distance = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_item_earn_redeem_merchant_distance);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        if (position % 2 == 1) {
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        } else {
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
        }

        if (merchant != null) {
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(merchant.getImage())) {
                Picasso.with(context)
                        .load(merchant.getImage())
                        .placeholder(R.drawable.icon_background_white)
                        //.transform(new CircleTransform())
                        .transform(new RoundedTransformation(4, 1))
                        .into(viewHolder.iv_item_earn_redeem_merchant_icon);
            }

            //System.out.println("---> merchant.getRewardsdesc(): " + merchant.getRewardsdesc());
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(merchant.getRewardslistingdesc())) {
                viewHolder.tv_item_earn_redeem_merchant_points.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                viewHolder.tv_item_earn_redeem_merchant_points.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            } else {
                viewHolder.tv_item_earn_redeem_merchant_points.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                viewHolder.tv_item_earn_redeem_merchant_points.setText(merchant.getRewardslistingdesc());
            }

            viewHolder.tv_item_earn_redeem_merchant_name.setText(merchant.getMerchantname());
            viewHolder.tv_item_earn_redeem_merchant_category.setText(merchant.getCategorydesc());


            return convertView;
        }


    }
    class ViewHolder {
        private ImageView iv_item_earn_redeem_merchant_icon;
        private TextView tv_item_earn_redeem_merchant_points;
        private TextView tv_item_earn_redeem_merchant_name;
        private TextView tv_item_earn_redeem_merchant_category;
        private TextView tv_item_earn_redeem_merchant_distance;
    }
}
```

Comment: if (position % 2 == 1) {
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        } else {
            convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
        }

Comment: you have to implement a custom adapter, which suit your own list item. Only you have your adapter ready, in your activity, you can call                       adapter = new EarnRedeemAdapter(getActivity(), list, true);
  listview_fragment_earn_redeem.setAdapter(adapter);