# Change text color of certain row in ListView

Tags: android, listview

I am new to android and java. I would like to make the text of the 3rd rows (not every third rows) in the ListView red color.

```
ArrayList<String> weekInfoList = new ArrayList<>();
weekInfoList.add("first row");
weekInfoList.add("second row");
weekInfoList.add("third row");

ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter1 = new ArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this, R.layout.list_item2, weekInfoList);
weeklyListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter1);

weeklyListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

     @Override
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {

     // intent to next activity
     }
});
```

Please help me.

Comment: you should use recyclerview instead

Comment: Check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13109840/android-alternate-row-colors-in-listview

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own custom `ArrayAdapter` instead of using the default, then override the [getView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#getView(int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup)) method to set the color depending on the row position.

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
        super(context, resource);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // check position
        // if every 3rd row, set color

        // return the modified convertView
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `BaseAdapter` or `ArrayAdapter` as @ginomempin suggested. and override `getView` method of it.

Now as you mentioned for every 3rd row you want to change text color, you can do following.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inf = (LayoutInflater) parent.getContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    final Holder vh;
    if (itemLayoutView == null) {
        vh = new Holder();
        itemLayoutView = inf.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout,
                    null);

        vh.textview = (TextView) itemLayoutView
                    .findViewById(R.id.textview);
        temLayoutView.setTag(vh);
    } else {
        vh = (Holder) itemLayoutView.getTag();
    }

    if(position%3==0){
        holder.textview.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ff0000"));
    }else{
        holder.textview.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#666666"));
    }

    return convertView;
}
```

For more details on how to use custom Adapter refer [This](http://androidexample.com/How_To_Create_A_Custom_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=67) and [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166497/custom-adapter-for-list-view)

Happy Coding.

Answer (score 0):

In your adapter class, you might have more than one item to display, so if you are using `android.support.v4` than it will be like,

```
holder.thirdTextview.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(activity, R.color.red));
```

Answer (score 0):

As I am very new to programming, I tried to avoid custom adapter but seems like we must use it.

The alternate answers are very brief. So here I attach my solution for more detail reference.

```
ArrayAdapter customAdapter = new MySimpleArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(),weekInfoList);
weeklyListView.setAdapter(customAdapter);

public class MySimpleArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    private final Context context;
    private final ArrayList<String> values;

    public MySimpleArrayAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> values) {
        super(context, -1, values);
        this.context = context;
        this.values = values;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item2, parent, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.weeknumber2);
        textView.setText(values.get(position));

        if (position==2){
            textView.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        }

        return rowView;
    }
}
```

Thanks to Suraj's solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/13109854/2466516.