# Altering Color of specific ListView Positions issue

Tags: android, arrays, listview

Hey so I'm trying to change the color of specific positions in a listview. Im able to change the color of the positions I want but there seems to be a pattern where 10 positions down the list from the item I want to highlight is also highlighted and I can't figure out why.

Heres how my custom adapter.java is set up with the color change code.

```
 package com.example.zach.listview;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;


class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{
public CustomAdapter(Context context, String[] routes) {
    super(context, R.layout.custom_row ,routes);
}
@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater routeInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    View customView = convertView;
    if(customView == null){customView = routeInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row, parent, false);}

    String singleRoute = getItem(position);
    TextView routeText = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.routeText);

    routeText.setText(singleRoute);

    //if (getItem(position).equals("Information")){
     //   routeText.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
    //}

    if(position == 0)
    {
        routeText.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
    }
    return customView;
}
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Alternate row Colors in ListView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13109840/android-alternate-row-colors-in-listview)

Comment: try recyclerview instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THis is because of recycling.  The same views are reused as you scroll.  If you set a value for a view, you must reset it to default in the else statement, or it will stay set when its recycled.

Basic rule of list views-  if you ever set something, always set it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way.

```
if(position == 0) {
    routeText.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
} else {
    routeText.setBackgroundColor(null); // or any other you want.
}
```

Hope this will help.

Happy coding.